# how to vertical align middle to multiple position absolute child div

Tags: jquery, html, css, center

I am currently facing a problem to vertical align the multiple position:absolute div to middle. Although I apply width:100% and height:100%, but the elements seems overflow too. Please help me on this. Thank you.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    <div class="section-1">
      <h2>Heading Here</h2>
      <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section-2">
      <p>Another text here.</p>
      <p>One more time.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.section-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20vw;
  width: 40vw;
  background: #ccc;
}
.section-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60vw;
  background: #375642;
  width: 40vw;
}
```

demo: https://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/jamzbX

I can't find a way to make those content at the current position and middle on this full screen height, except top:50% and minus it's height, but it's bad for responsive.

Comment: all you need is section classes to be vertically aligned to middle with respect to screen height, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **CSS Positioning**. Like:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-41px);
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-41px);
}
.section-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20vw;
  width: 40vw;
  background: #ccc;
}
.section-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60vw;
  background: #375642;
  width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    <div class="section-1">
      <h2>Heading Here</h2>
      <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section-2">
      <p>Another text here.</p>
      <p>One more time.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, it works if I want the content to be center, but actually I want to be that certain position.

Comment: .section-1 at left:20vw while .section-2 at left:60vw

Comment: oh, this is the way i know. it's not flexible enough for responsive content. i am looking for an effective way

Comment: i mean, what if my content height is 200px if resize to mobile size, yet the translateY is not fluid, but just adaptive

Answer (score 0):

If you need to vertically center all classes starting with section then: 

**CSS:**

```
div[class^='section-'], div[class*='section-']{
    position: absolute;
    left: 20vw;
    width: 40vw;
    background: #ccc;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Adding top and transform values in `%` should do the trick